# Set managedObjectContext of a UITableViewController with a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, uistoryboard

I have looked at other questions and answers but I still cannot set the `managedObjectContext` of a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Here is my current code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Learn"];

MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
}
```

However when I run the code, the app crashes and produces a log output of this:

```
+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
```

When I try just logging `NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectContext);` in the `MasterViewController` the result is `(null)

I created my `managedObjectContext` like so and it received no errors:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

**N.B.** I am trying to set a `UITableViewController` that is not the initial view controller

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: get it from your app delegate: `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]`

Comment: Show the creation of the MOC. Any errors?

Comment: where u have created ur managedObjectContext?

Comment: @Wain See edit of creation of managedObjectContext

Comment: Any errors during the creation then? Does it actually exist?

Comment: @Wain The application logged a positive: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xb09c950> in the App Delegate

Comment: Ok, so, where is the code where you call `entityForName` (or try to instantiate an entity)?

Comment: @Wain When my application attempts to load the MasterViewController with a UITableView displaying the data. My code for displaying the data worked fine before I changed MasterViewController not to be the initial view controller.

Comment: What is the initial view controller now then? Is it trying to do something with the MOC?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43465/discussion-between-alexander-macleod-and-wain)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the boilerplate Apple template (from Xcode), your app delegate should have a method like this, creating the managed objects dynamically when you call `self.managedObjectContext`:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Put a breakpoint there and check that you pass the correct context to the view controller. Make sure the VC property is `(nonatomic, strong)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation controller is set as the initial controller in the storyboard, then the problem is that you're instantiating a new instance of that navigation controller with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. You should get the reference to MasterViewController like this instead:

```
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
```